# What's in a Title - Senior Executive Assistant to Executive Assistant

Tags: job-change, united-states, title

I am a "senior executive assistant" to the president of a regional office  of a large company (10,000 employees - our office has 80 employees).  He is not the CEO, and there are regional managers between him and the CEO. There are many presidents of about 20 regional offices.

I am now being interviewed for "executive assistant" to the CEO (big cheese) of a smaller (50-200 employees) non profit. I will be the CEO's assistant and also handling meetings for the Board of Directors etc.

I am 55 and hope to stay in my next job until I retire.  BUT, if I have to find another job at some point, how worried should I be that I am going from senior EA to just plain old EA?

This is in Washington, DC. Salary and benefits and duties are about the same for both jobs except I will now be dealing directly with the Board of Directors.

Comment: Dwight Schrute is that you?

Comment: Go through the interview process and if offered the job, ask for the Sr part to be added to the title.  Should be no big deal.

Comment: You could ask for Senior, or even ask for "Assistant to the CEO" - just to drive the point home.

Comment: If you dont get a raise to go to your new position it will be seen as a step down.  And worst part is I would bet dollars to donuts that the new position will be a LOT more work

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be too concerned about this.  If you do have to change jobs, you can fairly easily explain away the issue of the titles as you did here- went from being executive's assistant to CEO's assistant, so definitely not a move down.

A positive of "moving down" in title is that it gives you room for upward salary growth when the CEO promotes you to Senior Executive Assistant.

Comment: Actually, that's the title of the new job "Executive Assistant to the CEO" - I guess that's how it will go on my resume if I ever need to get another job.  So, that's seems okay. Thank you all.  Oh, and to whomever changed the wording of my title - I am NOT in the software development field!!